# Attempting to add facebook like button to sencha toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

the like button is not showing.

**code snapshot**

**my html file :**

```
.
.
.
<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
.
.
.
```

**my js file:**

```
 .
 .
 .
var navtoolbar = {
xtype : 'toolbar',
title : Ext.String.ellipsis(titlevalue,20,true),
docked : 'top',
items : [backButton,spacer,
{xtype:'container',html:'<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://test.com" data-send="true" 
data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>'}]
};
 .
 .
 .
```

In another part of my application, i was able to show the like button(not on the toolbar).

```
this.getItems().items[0].setHtml('<div class="category-title" >'+this.getDataList()._contentTitle+' </div><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://test.com" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that should be added in order to obtain the facebook button in your toolbar:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();//facebook
```